# How to get PHP Post data into jquery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can't figure out how to get the blog title into the data field of the ajax call. I have been looking for tutorials on beginner SQL / PHP / AJAX and I am struggling so if anyone has any good tutorials for this kind of stuff I'd be happy to hear it. I understand jquery and php okay, but I am trying to set up a simple blog system where you can edit and delete posts using ajax requests and I am struggling big time. Thanks!

functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#deletePost').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"post_action.php",
        data: { action: "deletePost", postTitle: title of blog post },
        success: function(result){
            $('ul.left').html(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

index.php

```
<?php
            include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
            include 'scripts/functions.php';
            sec_session_start();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo'<div class="blog"><h3 class="blog">' . $row['Title'] . 
                "</h3><h3>" . $row['Date'] . "</h3><h3>" . $row['Tag'] . 
                "</h3><hr>";
                echo'<p class="blog">' . $row['Body'] . '</p><form name="postForm" 
                method="post" action="process_post.php">
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" 
                value="editPost" class="postButton"  type="button">Edit</input>
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" value="deletePost" 
                class="postButton" type="button">Delete</input>
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" value="commentPost" 
                class="postButton"  type="button">Comment</input>
                </form></div>';
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you want to do. Can you describe exactly what you want to happen (in words)? Trivial answer to "how to get the blog title into the data field" is "stick a variable where you have `title of blog post`", but I doubt that answers anything for you.

Comment: You can't use the same `id` in each element in a loop, IDs have to be unique.

Comment: In my javascript file on the line "postTitle: title of blog post" How do I get the data from $row['Title'] on the index.php file

Comment: @Barmar I fixed this now in the post, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat `id="deletePost"` in each blog post. You should use a class instead. Then you can write:

```
$('.deletePost').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"post_action.php",
        data: { action: "deletePost",
                postTitle: $(this).siblings("h3.blog").text()
        },
        success: function(result){
            $('ul.left').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. I was thinking too much about Ajax to realise OP's trouble is with DOM navigation. :)

Comment: Awesome answer Barmar, thanks. I like the way you presented a solution that works using the siblings selector. But your original answer (or maybe it was @Amadan) you suggested giving my buttons a "val" attribute and storing the blog title in that? Can you explain more about JSON and why I have to return one with index.php? Thanks!

Comment: It was Bonakid's answer, and he deleted it because it was not appropriate for your situation.

Comment: @CodeManiak: It was neither of us. The JSON thing was irrelevant and incorrect. But it would probably be easier for everyone including the computer if you didn't use the title attribute but the primary key column (usually called `id` or `post_id`) to tell your server what you're talking about. You can write it like this: `<h3 class="blog" data-id="<?php $row['id']: ?>">` and use that value instead of the title.

Comment: I had another question about this... In pseudocode I want to do this

    `if $_GET['action'] == "deletePost"`
       `deletePost($_GET['title'];`


post_action.php



   ` <?php`
 `function deletePost($title){`
  `$sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE Title = '$title';";`
  `mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);`
 `}`
   ` ?>`

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to ask there. It's not helped by the fact that you can't format code in comments.